# Is it possible to provide proxy.ashx for the other domain?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, proxy

Usually, we use `proxy.ashx` for the same domain by this code. (working well.)

```
esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "proxy.ashx"; 
esri.config.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = true;
```

If the other domain need to use my proxy, is it possible to provide `proxy.ashx` for the other domain?

I have try from my localhost but not working

```
esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "http://www.mydomain.com/proxy.ashx"; //can't access
esri.config.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, A JavaScript App on *another Domain* can't use your proxy directly.

You need to understand that JavaScript has a major limitation. It can't directly access resources (excluding images) from another domain. This is generally why a proxy is used inthe first place; to access the resources from an ArcGIS server or other services which are on another domain.

In many cases, the proxy is also used for authentication; If this is what you are using the proxy for, then you'll have to figure out some other way of hitting this proxy. Maybe a proxy on the other domain, which hits this proxy.

---

*Clarification:* JavaScript can access services on other domains using [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), but I've always had problems using CORS with the ESRI JSAPI.